# How can I find strings that have mixed cased with Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, ack

I'm trying to filter thousands of files, looking for those which contain string constants with mixed case. Such strings can be embedded in whitespace, but may not contain whitespace themselves. So the following (containing UC chars) are matches:

```
"  AString "   // leading and trailing spaces together allowed
"AString "     // trailing spaces allowed
"  AString"    // leading spaces allowed
"newString03"  // numeric chars allowed
"!stringBIG?"  // non-alphanumeric chars allowed
"R"            // Single UC is a match
```

but these are not:

```
"A String" // not a match because it contains an embedded space
"Foo bar baz" // does not match due to multiple whitespace interruptions
"a_string" // not a match because there are no UC chars
```

I still want to match on lines which contain *both* patterns:

```
"ABigString", "a sentence fragment" // need to catch so I find the first case...
```

I want to use Perl regexps, preferably driven by the [ack](http://betterthangrep.com/) command-line tool. Obviously, *\w* and *\W* are not going to work. It seems that *\S* should match the non-space chars. I can't seem to figure out how to embed the requirement of "at least one upper-case character per string"...

```
ack --match '\"\s*\S+\s*\"'
```

is the closest I've gotten. I need to replace the *\S+* with *something* that captures the "at least one upper-case (ascii) character (in any position of the non-whitespace string)" requirement.

This is straightforward to program in C/C++ (and yes, Perl, procedurally, without resorting to regexps), I'm just trying to figure out if there is a regular expression which can do the same job.

Comment: Does "mixed case" mean it has to contain *both* uppercase and lowercase letters?

Comment: Actually, no. I've added an example, "R" which should also match. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following pattern passes all your tests:

```
qr/
  "      # leading single quote

  (?!    # filter out strings with internal spaces
     [^"]*   # zero or more non-quotes
     [^"\s]  # neither a quote nor whitespace
     \s+     # internal whitespace
     [^"\s]  # another non-quote, non-whitespace character
  )

  [^"]*  # zero or more non-quote characters
  [A-Z]  # at least one uppercase letter
  [^"]*  # followed by zero or more non-quotes
  "      # and finally the trailing quote
/x
```

Using this test program—that uses the above pattern without `/x` and therefore without whitespace and comments—as input to `ack-grep` (as `ack` is called on Ubuntu)

```
#! /usr/bin/perl

my @tests = (
  [ q<"  AString ">   => 1 ],
  [ q<"AString ">     => 1 ],
  [ q<"  AString">    => 1 ],
  [ q<"newString03">  => 1 ],
  [ q<"!stringBIG?">  => 1 ],
  [ q<"R">            => 1 ],
  [ q<"A String">     => 0 ],
  [ q<"a_string">     => 0 ],
  [ q<"ABigString", "a sentence fragment"> => 1 ],
  [ q<"  a String  "> => 0 ],
  [ q<"Foo bar baz">  => 0 ],
);

my $pattern = qr/"(?![^"]*[^"\s]\s+[^"\s])[^"]*[A-Z][^"]*"/;
for (@tests) {
  my($str,$expectMatch) = @$_;
  my $matched = $str =~ /$pattern/;
  print +($matched xor $expectMatch) ? "FAIL" : "PASS",
        ": $str\n";
}
```

produces the following output:

```
$ ack-grep '"(?![^"]*[^"\s]\s+[^"\s])[^"]*[A-Z][^"]*"' try
  [ q<"  AString ">   => 1 ],
  [ q<"AString ">     => 1 ],
  [ q<"  AString">    => 1 ],
  [ q<"newString03">  => 1 ],
  [ q<"!stringBIG?">  => 1 ],
  [ q<"R">            => 1 ],
  [ q<"ABigString", "a sentence fragment"> => 1 ],
my $pattern = qr/"(?![^"]*[^"\s]\s+[^"\s])[^"]*[A-Z][^"]*"/;
  print +($matched xor $expectMatch) ? "FAIL" : "PASS",
```

With the C shell and derivatives, you have to escape the bang:

```
% ack-grep '"(?\![^"]*[^"\s]\s+[^"\s])[^"]*[A-Z][^"]*"' ...
```

I wish I could preserve the highlighted matches, but that doesn't seem to be [allowed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed).

Note that escaped double-quotes (`\"`) will severely confuse this pattern.

Comment: That is a thing of beauty, sort of. ;^)~  Now if I can figure out how to escape it for the shell, I can use it with ack!

Comment: Just use single quotes. See my revised answer.

Comment: Is ack-grep just an alias for ack? I have version 1.88 of ack. Also, with c-shell, the single quoted version fails: [: Event not found.

Comment: But Bourne shell seems to work. Okay, I have my answer! Thanks @gbacon!

Comment: See revised answer. Glad to help!

Comment: @gbacon, Actually, probably due to my poorly worded spec, it still incorrectly matches when there are more than one internal whitespace sequences: "Foo bar baz" matches, but should not as it is multiple words. I'll see if I can fix it now that I have some clues to the pattern...

Comment: What about `"  a String  "`? I assume it should not match either.

Comment: @gbacon: True. *Any* number of interruptions of non-whitespace chars with whitespace chars disqualifies the string. Only leading and trailing whitespace are allowed.

Comment: ack-grep is how some Linux distros package ack, because there is already a package out there called ack.

Comment: @gbacon's revised answer (truly, this time) wins the prize! Thanks, sir!

Answer (score 0):

You could add the requirement with a character class, like:

```
ack --match "\"\s*\S+[A-Z]\S+\s*\""
```

I'm assuming that `ack` matches one line at a time.  The `\S+\s*\"` part can match multiple closing quotes in a row.  It would match the entirety of `"alfa""`, instead of just `"alfa"`.

Comment: ack, not awk ;^)~

   It embeds in Perl or runs as a command line, and thus uses Perl regexps: http://betterthangrep.com/.

But I can still consider awk, of course. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, and as written, doesn't yours require the upper case char as the last char in the non-space string? I need to require the UC char *anywhere* in the non-space string.

Comment: @Don Wakefield: Right, I kinda wondered about the new AWK `--match` option :)  The regex should work in Perl tho

Comment: @Don Wakefield: It has `\S+` both before and after `[A-Z]`, so it doesn't require the cap at end of string

Comment: But I think it does require the capital *not* to be at the end of the string if there's only one of it, in other words, "abcD" won't match.

Comment: @Dan is right. The requirement is "at least one UC char, *anywhere* in the non-whitespace character string" and there can be no additional accidental constraint which amounts to "just at the beginning", "just at the end" or "at least *two* (three, four) UC chars"...

Comment: Won't that match ABCD?  Or, is all caps an okay string to match?

Comment: Yes, all caps is okay to match. But the pattern really only matches strings with caps anchored to the ends of the non-whitespace string. So "ABCD" matches, and "ABxyCD", but not "abXYcd", which should.